# How to check rejected edit suggestions by post ID?

Tags: support, search, rejected-edits

While an approved edit can simply be checked in any post's edit history, the only ways to check rejected edits are either checking the suggester's suggestion history or one's own review history if one happened to review said edit. Isn't there a simpler way to check a rejected suggestion given only a post id?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/ can help, but data there is about week old. Other then that no easy way and actually can't think of proper way: adding special notice in the post revision is probably too much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moderators can do this: in the mod menu under the post, select “show review history”. A review on a suggested edit on a post counts as a review on the post even if the suggested edit is rejected. This is a fairly recent feature, I think it was introduced in 2013 with little publicity. This only applies to questions and answers, not to tag wikis.

If you have 10k privileges, you can browse the [suggested edit review history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history). You can only search page by page, so on Stack Overflow this is only practical if you can pinpoint the time of the suggestion pretty well (on SO, one page is currently about 10 minutes).

You can retrieve suggested edits through the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), via the [`/posts/{ids}/suggested-edits` method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-suggested-edits). Select the desired site under “Try It” and enter the post ID (the number after `/questions/`, `/q/` or `/a/` in the URL) in the “ids” box.

If the suggested edit is old enough to be included in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (which is a static copy of the public part of the database of graduated sites, updated every few weeks), you can [look it up there](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/127462/all-suggested-edits-on-a-post).

Comment: I see. It would be nice if at least on own posts this would be available for everyone, since OP might consider a rejected "too radical" edit actually good

Comment: [Request to make this available for everyone on their own posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192238/146482)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I'd missed that yesterday, but the data is also accessible through the API. I'd looked under `/suggested-edits`, but it's under `/posts`. So you could write a user script.