# Make the "show review history" mod-tool available on suggested edits for everyone (at least on own posts)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

As I [previously noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192059/146482),

> While an *approved* edit can simply be checked in any post's edit history, the only ways to check *rejected* edits are either checking the suggester's suggestion history or one's own review history if one happened to review said edit.

As Gilles stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192063/146482),

> in the mod menu under the post, select “show review history”. A review on a suggested edit on a post counts as a review on the post even if the suggested edit is rejected. This is a fairly recent feature, I think it was introduced in 2013 with little publicity.

i.e. there already exists a tool to show not only approved edits but also refused ones. And at least for one's own posts it would be adequate being able to re-view (or even re-review) them to make sure e.g. a "too radical" suggestion wasn't actually fixing a more or less severe oversight. **edit2** Though there's probably no reason why this shouldn't be available for just anyone.

**edit** As Gilles said, the tool actually also shows all other review history items like low quality etc. I'm only requesting access to the suggested edit history. (Although as long as the rest doesn't expose too much user information it'd probably be less implementation work to use the tool as-is but only make it available on own posts unless one is a mod.)

Comment: That mod tool shows all review history (first posts, close, etc.), not just suggested edits. Your request is only about suggested edits, right?

Comment: @Gilles Ah true, I didn't notice that, edited it in. Yes, I'm only referring to suggested edits. (Though in fact that complete history might be helpful for users to self-improve, but I'm not sure whether this would provide too much sensitive information to a non-mod)

Comment: I don't see the point of having this feature for just for one's own posts: we already get a notice of suggested edits in the supercollider.

Comment: @Gilles Does it still show up if the edit was rejected before you logged in? The only suggested edit currently in mine was approved, and is hidden well between many bounty/badge notifications. Anyway, the supercollider tends to be good for immediate information, but e.g. after a longer vacation it probably won't even show up there anymore **edit** sure I can browse the stackexchange.com inbox, but that is not even searchable

Comment: I've often seen notifications of edits on my posts after they'd been rejected, and once or twice pursued a rejector to chastise him for rejecting a correct edit. But it's true that they don't survive long, so you might not see them all after a short vacation. Still, I don't see the point of restricting that history to the author.

Comment: @Gilles So you are not against making this available but against restricting it to mods and respective OP? Sure, I'd also prefer this made available for everyone. I just though since currently it's only for mods making it available to a post's OP only would seem to be more in the spirit of whatever reason this is currently a mod-only tool. Then again, there's probably no reason why rejected edits shouldn't simply be browse-/viewable for everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After thinking about it a little, I think this would be a useful feature, but only in a narrow set of circumstances. UI-wise, the rejected edits should show up in the revision history, because suggested edits to an older revision would be confusing if shown against the current version. There could be a “show rejected edits” checkbox at the bottom of the revision history, which adds links to rejected edits in the right place in the history.

I don't see any point in restricting this, it can be public. After all the data does end up in the data explorer eventually. The review list moderator tools is restricted to moderators because it links to other review queues: first posts, close votes, etc. In fact that tool was added for moderation-related tasks related to the review queues other than suggested edits, such as “who let this spam through the late answers queue?”, or pushing a question out of the close queue after it has been edited. These queues are intended to show the review items somewhat randomly to users, and it is by design that there is no easy way to find the review item from the post. This logic doesn't apply to suggested edits: they're linked from the post when they're live, after all.

What bothers me about this feature is that it's a lot of code for a very narrow use case. I wouldn't want to have a new button under the post or to have all rejected edits show up in the revision history, that would be too disruptive, it's rare to want to see the rejected edits.

This could be implemented as a user script, as [the information is accessible through the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-suggested-edits).

Comment: Indeed having rejected edits show up in the usual revision history would be even better. I just thought it'd be less effort for the SE team to simply enable the existing mod-tool for everyone. But ultimately I'd also prefer the former version

Answer (score 4):

As of today, [you can find links to completed review tasks via the timeline for any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275795/should-the-new-timeline-view-show-links-to-review-items).

This works for *all* review types, not just suggested edits. However, they only become visible once the review has completed to avoid encouraging spoiling.

Credit to Adam Lear for the implementation here.